# If I delete Facebook activity log entries, how does that affect my available data?

Tags: facebook

I'm running a macro (iMacro for Chrome) that just goes through and kills comments (still building my like/react macro, having trouble with conditionals in the macro language.)

My questions: What exactly am I wiping? And how thorough/effective is this wipe? And is killing this activity on my (client-facing) version of Facebook actually wiping this activity? I'm guessing Facebook keeps backup/server-side copies of the activity logs...but how available are they? Is it a case of "available only after Facebook is subpoena'd"...or does no one really know?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting activity log will delete the log from your timeline. all activities will be there on your Timeline and it also be available there on Facebook server side.
You can get all your data by [downloading a copy of your Facebook data](https://www.facebook.com/help/302796099745838).